# Extract text only from the first square brackets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

If I have a string such as:

```
[text1]Blablablabla[text2]blalal
```

How do I extract only what is inside first `[]`?

I use this formula to extract content between `[]`

```
REGEXEXTRACT(B52, "\[(.+)\]")
```

With above formula I would get: `text1][text2`.

Not sure how to limit it only for the first pair of `[]` though, where I would get only `text1`

Comment: All you needed was to use a lazy instead of greedy quantifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this expression might simply work:

```
REGEXEXTRACT(B52, "^\[(.+?)\]")
```

or if lookarounks are supported,

```
REGEXEXTRACT(B52, "(?<=^\[)[^\]]*")
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/T6RaC8/1/)

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Fql5z8/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/Fql5z8/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Thank you very much! I just modified it a little bit in case first brackets are not at the beginning of the string (i.e. removed ^).

Answer (score 0):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1, "]"), "\[(.+)")
```

[image: 0]

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\[(.+?)\]")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Great alternative solution, sir. I will try to experiment more with it. You have been helping me a lot with regex lately :))

Comment: wish I can mark more than one answer as correct :(